# Does SABRE provide REST API for Air Seat booking and ticket?

Tags: rest, api, sabre

Currently I am working on WEB Application that using SABRE REST API calls to search and book a flight. At SABRE DEV STUDIO I visit the REST and SOAP API Calls section.

I am confuse about SABRE REST API calls because there are no any reservation/booking REST API call, how can I book seat using REST API. Same for the ticketing.

Comment: If you want a quick response you should ask your Sabre contact. Sabre Dev Studio displays only the services that are included in your agreement. If a service doesn't appear, it may mean that your company hasn't bought it yet, or that it doesn't exist

Comment: I am a sabre customer. currently i am using a REST API to search and Booking Seat, and successfully create a PNR.. now i want to send a request to create a ticket.i didn't see any REST API call for ticking.. do you have information about about REST ticketing API?

Comment: That was obvious from the start.  *Ask your Sabre contact!!*. Only *they* can answer whether they have such a REST API, whether your contract includes it or what their plans are

Comment: Or check the [REST API section](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/REST_APIs) at Sabre Dev Studio. If you don't see the relevant API, it doesn't mean that it's missing, it may mean that you haven't bought it. Sabre Dev Studio shows only the APIs you have access to

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the absence of API calls can only be explained by technical support personnel.

Answer (score 3):

REST API is still a new product so not every functionality is offered at the moment.
You can reserve seats and issue tickets with SOAP API.

Comment: Can we  use Create Passenger Name Record (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/) REST API for booking/reservation?

Comment: That service is only available to Sabre customers. If you do not have an API agreement, I'd advise you to use the Contact Us/Become a Sabre customer form on DevStudio in order to get in contact with a sales representative.

Comment: I am a sabre customer. currently i am using a  REST API to search and Booking Seat, and successfully create a PNR.. now i want to send a request to create a ticket.i didn't see any REST API call for ticking.. do you have information about about REST ticketing API?

Comment: @AhmadWali why don't you *ask* them? It's over a week since the original question. They would have answered already. Did you search in `developer.sabre.com` ?

Comment: no theres is no any answer regarding this..i already sent my questions to sabre support but no answer. :-(